# Ordering of analytical events

Tags: web-services, distributed-computing, analytics

My team is working on an analytics system for the web app. The web app has a service-oriented architecture, and all events are gathered in one centralized analytics service. The system is sending events from the front-end and back-end; these are requirements of the product team. However, the engineering team has stuck into an ordering issue. For example, we expect that front-end event A must come before the back-end event B, but it does not happen. At the moment, we use client time as the time of the event, but the client's clock can be completely wrong. There is a plan to avoid that issue by relying on the difference between the client's event time and the time of the event arrival using the formula:

`real event time` = `analytics service time` - (`client's event time` - `event arrival time`)

Still, this approach does not provide any guarantees, and we may continue to run into out-of-order events(though a small percentage is expected).

Is it even possible to guarantee the order of events while processing them on the analytics service? If yes, how? Maybe, tradeoffs I mentioned already provide a decent design. What is the state-of-the-art approach to the problem?

Comment: So the events are being generated by different computers, all being reported back to a central monitor (the analytics server), and you want to ensure that the monitor can properly order the events as they occurred in real-time?

Comment: @Nat correct, you perfectly summed it up.

Comment: Not sure what's the problem if you sort by event arrival time (timestamp that recorded in the analytic service)? Does it take events to have different transient time from other instance to the analytic server?

Comment: @lennon310 sorry, I didn't mention that. Events from the front-end may fail to deliver(due to the network, for example). We agreed to retry the delivery. It means that the delivery timestamp may be past the actual event timestamp. Also, no issues with the events from other services so far.

Comment: Can you have an event_time field in the events so it represents the time of creation regardless of how much delay you have due to retry?

Comment: @lennon310 I used to have it, but as time in the client's browser is not reliable it breaks funnels for the product management team. This is why my goal is to guarantee a certain ordering of events.

Comment: What timescales are we talking about between event A and event B and what is the typical latency between all the involved machines (assuming no reties take place)?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau All events appear on some user action, so the timescale is a matter of seconds, not less. Bearing in mind that some events come from the browser the latency is very broad. I cannot tell you the latency between servers though, it is not something we measured. Also, not sure about the geographical location of those servers, don't have access to the cloud dashboard. How crucial is this information, do you think about something in particular?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your front end is not malicious and not purposefully manipulating the time, you can follow this procedure:

1. Modify the message so that it contains two timestamps: (A) The time the event happened and (B) the current time-- both according to the client's own clock.
2. If transmission of an event fails, the front end should keep the original value of A but keep updating B with each retry.
3. When the event is received by the server, compute the difference between the actual system time (according to the server) and the current time reported by the client (field B). Call this difference C.
4. Compute the actual event time as A - C. This gives you the time of the event, corrected for the difference between server time and client time. Call this D.
5. Sort your events by D.

This procedure allows the client to use its own timestamp while truing up the client's clock to server time. It also neatly avoids any issue with time zone or DST.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think the solution you described will work for me. However, there is still a chance that the minor part of events will be stored out-of-order if, let's say, time will be changed between A and B events. Again, I think this solution will work and will be more or less reliable to make business decisions, but I wonder if there exist any algorithms that provide some guarantees. I've read about distributed consensus, but it seems it is not supposed to be run on servers and browsers simultaneously(without a painful headache at least).